# What's the difference between perfect security and unconditional security?

Tags: security-definition

[This](https://iacr.org/archive/tcc2008/49480207/49480207.pdf) paper refers to two distinct security models: perfect security and unconditional security. Until now, I knew of them as the same thing and equivalent to information-theoretic security.

[image]

From the paper, it's obvious that perfect security is the same as information-theoretic security. In this case, what exactly is unconditional security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the references, both perfect security and unconditional security consider adversaries that have unlimited computational power, i.e., information-theoretic security. I think the only difference is that unconditional security allows for **negligible** failure while perfect security requires **zero** failure.